# CSS background image resizing

Tags: html, css, background

I would like it so that when you resize the screen it cuts off the image from the edges so that the text stays in the same spot on the image.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>TapeKings</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

<body>
<div id="home" class="banner">
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">

  </div>
  <div class="head-logo">
    <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/ndpqab5l1/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="banner-info">
    <h3>Custom tape designs taken<br/>to the next level</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body,html {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nav {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
background-color: #000000;
}

.banner {
text-align: center;
background: url(http://s32.postimg.org/yhfqblzid/img1.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
background-size: 1920px;
width: 100%;
min-height: 959px;
}

.head-logo {
margin-top: 250px;
text-align: center;
}

.head-logo img {
height: 140px;
width: 140px;
}

.banner-info {
margin-top: 25px;
text-align: center;
}

.banner-info h3 {
color: #000000;
margin: 16px 0;
font-size: 40px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle for my site: https://jsfiddle.net/bnhvnnL7/

Thanks!

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L6ecf2kL/?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, not sure why I didn't think of that but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `background-position: center;` to your .banner div:

```
.banner {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(http://s32.postimg.org/yhfqblzid/img1.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  background-size: 1920px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 959px;
  background-position:center;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. 
I put all thinks to the vertical center div.
In max-width you can set the size of max width you wonna.
Div is always in center of vertical and horizontal position.
It will look good on phone or other small screen.
Regards.

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-image: url('http://s32.postimg.org/yhfqblzid/img1.jpg');
}
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    max-width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner img
{
  height: 140px;
}
.inner h3 {
  color: #000000;
  margin: 16px 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/ndpqab5l1/logo.png">
        <h3>Custom tape designs taken<br/>to the next level</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```